# changing id's of TD tags dynamically is not permanent

Tags: javascript

I want to change Id of TD tag dynamically. I tried following

```
var div_node;           

div_node = document.getElementById(old_id);

div_node.id = new_id;
```

but effect of changing Id is not permanent. if I write some statements after this, it give original id only. I mean If I do alert(div_node.id), It gives original Id Only.

here is My Whole Program.

jsAnim.js is javascript library. i have included it. Available at
http://jsanim.com/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsAnim.js"> </script>

        <script>

        function Assign_id()   //This function Will execute onload
        {
        j=0;
        for(i=1;i<4;i++)C
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName("td")[j].setAttribute("id",i);
            //alert(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[j].id);
            j++;
        }
        }

        function getdata()
        {
            var old_id=prompt("Enter Box Id.");
            var new_id=prompt("Enter New Position");
            animate(old_id,new_id);
            change_id(old_id,new_id);

        }

        function animate(old_id,new_id)
        {
            var manager=new jsAnimManager();
            obj=document.getElementById(old_id);
            obj.style.position="relative";
            var anim=manager.createAnimObject(old_id);
            anim.add({property: Prop.top, to: 100, duration: 2000});
            anim.add({property: Prop.left, to: ((new_id-old_id)*50)+4, duration: 2000});
            anim.add({property: Prop.top, to: 0, duration: 2000});

            obj=document.getElementById(new_id);
            obj.style.position="relative";
            var anim=manager.createAnimObject(new_id);
            anim.add({property: Prop.bottom, to: 100, duration: 2000});
            anim.add({property: Prop.right, to: ((new_id-old_id)*50)+4, duration: 2000});
            anim.add({property: Prop.bottom, to: 0, duration: 2000});
        }

        function change_id(old_id,new_id)
        {
            var div_node;
            div_node = document.getElementById(old_id);
            div_node.id = new_id;
            alert(div_node.id);     //HERE IT IS GIVING CORRECT CHANGED ID;

            var div_node1 = document.getElementById(new_id);
            div_node1.id = old_id;

            alert(div_node.id);     //BUT HERE IT AGAIN GIVE ORIGINAL ID ONLY
            alert(div_node1.id);
        }
    </script>
</head>



<body onload="Assign_id()">

    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>

    <td width="50" height="100" background="pic.png">
    <font size="10" align="center">A</font>
    </td>

    <td width="50" height="100" background="pic.png">
    <font size="10" align="center">B</font>
    </td>


    <td width="50" height="100" background="pic.png">
    <font size="10" align="center">C</font>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <button onclick="getdata()"> NEXT </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `jsAnimManager`?

Comment: what is `jsAnim.js`, can't just leave code out, might be an issue there, also what is your rationale for swapping ID's ?? Why not just do classes? (style/position?)

Comment: Don't use "setAttribute()" to set the "id" of a DOM element in your "Assign_ID()" function. Just set it as a property directly on the object, as you do in the rest of the code.

Comment: @Neal and Jakub : jsAnim.js is library. http://jsanim.com/

Answer (score 1):

You get the element with ID `old_id`, then set its ID to `new_id`.

Then you get the element with ID `new_id`. This is the same element as above (as you just set its ID to `new_id`). You then set this elements ID to `old_id` again.

`div_node` and `div_node1` are the same element. You just swap the ID and then swap it back.

Comment: As per your suggestion I changed My change_id function As follows
 but its not changing Id of A

var div_node;
   var temp="0"

   div_node = document.getElementById(old_id);
   div_node.id = temp;
   
   var div_node1 = document.getElementById(new_id);
   div_node1.id = old_id;
   
   var div_node2 = document.getElementById(temp);
   div_node2.id = new_id;
   
   alert(div_node2.id);
   alert(div_node1.id);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Are you having ID collisions? Each ID should be unique on the page. I don't see any safe guards in your code at first glance.

Just to rule things out, you'd also want to change the id before animating.